# Why my CSS file is empty after the LESS file is compiled?

Tags: jquery, html, css, less

I use LESS css and I am new to it. in my LESS file I have several variables for different colors:

```
@LightBlue: #0088CC;
@DarkPink: #C71C77;
@LightGreen: #76B51B;
```

I set `@LightBlue` as the default color:

```
@DefaultThemeColor: @LightBlue;
```

I created another LESS file, `dark-pink.less` to change the color of the theme. and in this file I just changed the variable color like this:

```
@LightGreen: #76B51B;

@DefaultThemeColor: @LightGreen;
```

but after it is compiled to CSS file, I noticed that the CSS file is empty. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use the variable within some mixin/class etc. If you just set the variable a value, LESS would not produce any output. Try `.LightGreenTheme{background: @DefaultThemeColor;}`. This should produce an output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far you have only set the variables, you haven't used them in any selector so less has nothing to compile.

Assigning any one of the variables like this for example should produce CSS in the compiled css file:

```
@LightGreen: #76B51B;

@DefaultThemeColor: @LightGreen; 

h1 { /* Use the variable like this */
    color:@LightGreen
}
```

Comment: Within the code formatted blocks, `**` will not make the text as bold mate and it looks a bit odd, so I changed it and added a comment next to it. Please feel free to roll back if you wish to :)